# returning value with the highest frequency

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:

```
name  gender country
john   1      us
john   0      cn
john   0      us
john   0       us
lisa   0      us
lisa   1      fr
lisa   1      us
lisa.   1    us
```

I am hoping to keep the location information but return the gender value with the highest frequency. for example, there are three johns from us and one from cn. I will keep the john from cn, for johns in the us, I return the one with highest frequency which is 0.

The final return dataframe should be

```
 name  gender   country
 john   0      cn
 john   0     us
lisa     1     fr
lisa     1     us
```

anyone has any suggestions?

```
df[df.groupby(['name', ['code']).gender.transform('nunique').gt(1)]
```

I tried this to return the unique gender value with the higest frequency, but this doesn't give me any dataframe.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Let us try `groupby` with `mode`

```
s = df.groupby(['name','country']).gender.apply(lambda x :x.mode()[0]).reset_index()
Out[12]: 
   name country  gender
0  john      cn       0
1  john      us       0
2  lisa      fr       1
3  lisa      us       1
```

Comment: is there anyway to make the runtime shorter? the data was big and this code takes a really long time to run